# sed + remove character on the first match or on the second match

Tags: linux, bash, sed

the following sed syntax remove the "#" in the line "Require all granted"

```
   sed 's/#\([[:space:]]*Require all granted\)/ \1/' graphite-web.conf

   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

how to change the sed syntax in order to remove the "#" on the first match ? or  for  the second match ?

expected output:

```
   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

or

```
   #<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

Comment: Using `sed` here when other tools are far better suited (e.g. `awk`) is a bad idea except, perhaps, as an academic exercise (or other form of self-punishment). :)

Comment: A lot of people took the time to try to answer your question. If any of the answers were useful I'm sure they'd appreciate an upvote. And if you're using one of the solutions please "accept" it. If none of the answers are useful please indicate what is missing. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `awk` instead

```
$ cat ip.txt 
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Deny

$ awk '/#[[:space:]]*Require all granted/ && ++c==1{sub("#", " ")} 1' ip.txt
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Deny

$ awk '/#[[:space:]]*Require all granted/ && ++c==2{sub("#", " ")} 1' ip.txt
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Deny

$ awk '/#[[:space:]]*Require all granted/ && ++c>1{sub("#", " ")} 1' ip.txt
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
        Require all granted
   #    Order Deny
```

See also [awk save modifications in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16529716/awk-save-modifications-in-place)

Or, using `perl`

```
$ # for inplace editing, use perl -i -pe
$ perl -pe 's/#/ / if /#\s*Require all granted/ && ++$c==1' ip.txt
   #    Allow from All
        Require all granted
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Deny
```

Comment: one of the negative by using awk is that awk cant update the file and need to redirect the output to other file and then copy it to the original , unless you have better idea as sed use the -i option

Comment: with GNU awk you can use `-i inplace` and having to use `> tmp && mv tmp ip.txt` is hardly a bother compared to complicated solution you'd need in `sed`

Comment: @yael, the best practice is to backup all configuration files, especially while processing inside scripts. That's why `awk` approach is the same as `sed`

Answer (score 0):

Or `sed` approach:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/#\([[:space:]]*Require all granted\)/ \1/2' graphite-web.conf
```

If input file contain:

```
#<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
   #    Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

Output will be:

```
#<IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.4
   #    Require local
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Allow from All
   #    Require all granted
   #</IfModule>
   #<IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
   #    # Apache 2.2
        Require all granted
   #    Order Allow,Deny
   #    Deny from all
   #    Allow from All
   #    Allow from ::1
   #</IfModule>
```

This pattern `:a;N;$!ba;` reads all lines (like a while loop) before end of file and after eof has reached it execute replacing `s///2` of second occurence.

The best explanation of sed labels you may read in [What is the meaning of :a;$!N; in a sed command?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461191/what-is-the-meaning-of-an-in-a-sed-command)

And read similar topic [How to replace the nth occurrence of a string using sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13817798/how-to-replace-the-nth-occurrence-of-a-string-using-sed)

Answer (score 0):

**Sed** is meant to work on streams. An easy way to accomplish of what you want is to use `ed`:

```
ed -s graphite-web.conf <<<$'/Require all/s/#/ /\nw'
```

Update:
I can go into details about `ed` but this [page](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/howto/edit-ed) explains `ed` and its extensive usage in much more details.

My explanation for this line is:

`-s` means quite. Don't show what we changed.

Then we use herestring `<<<` and apply ANSI C `$''` form of quotation in which the backslash character combinations are expanded. `\nw` means we add a new line and write to the file.

Comment: +1 for use of `ed`. -1 for not providing explanation for those unfamiliar with `ed`.

Comment: @BLayer See the update. Also see the page which explains in great detail how `ed` works and what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `ex` version...set shell variable `x` to a number indicating which occurrence to change (e.g. with `x=2` the command will modify the second occurrence of the pattern)...

This one updates the input file in-place:

```
ex +'/#\(\s*Require all granted\)/|1' +"norm ${x}n" +'s// \1/|wq' file
```

Here's a piped variant that doesn't modify the file but prints the modified version to *stdout*:

```
cat file | ex +'/#\(\s*Require all granted\)/|1' +"norm ${x}n" +'s// \1/' +'%p|q!' /dev/stdin
```

---

**Details:**

When it's not being run interactively `ex` is essentially a cmdline-mode-centric, batched version of `vim`. So a lot of this should be familiar to `vim` users...

- `/#\(\s*Require all granted\)/|1` - search for the pattern then go to line 1 to "reset"
- `norm ${x}n` - go the `n`ext occurrence of the pattern `x` times
- `s// \1/|wq` - do the substitution on current line only then write-quit